# typescript-axios openapi generator import errors

Tags: typescript, openapi-generator

After generating models with the cli for a vue3 application with the typescript-axios generator I get two types of typescript errors at the import level:

```
TS1371: This import is never used as a value and must use 'import type' because 'importsNotUsedAsValues' is set to 'error'.
TS1444: 'ExampleDto' is a type and must be imported using a type-only import when 'preserveValueImports' and 'isolatedModules' are both enabled.
```

I'm generating my files with the following command:

```
npx @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli generate -i ../path/to/webapi-spec.yml -g typescript-axios -o ./src/generated/openapi --additional-properties=withSeparateModelsAndApi=true,apiPackage=api,modelPackage=models --global-property models
```

Is there any way to turn these errors off?

Comment: I know this is not fully a solution but, the problem is that `typescript-axios` templates simply not has `import type` lines. Hence generated code doesn't has separate value imports & type imports. However the workaround is simply generate the code with your custom templates. Basically take the templates here: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/typescript-axios and put into a folder, change  then give the folder path to the generate command with `-t` flag.